# Change package search paths

Tags: texlive, installing, linux

I was previously running a manually installed TeXlive 2013 (as in https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

Now I have removed this with the according button in tlmng (TeXlive Manager) and installed TeXlive 2015 with the Manjaro package manager.

When I try to compile my documents I get a lot of errors that some libraries or package options are not found. Those are all files and options that were introduced between TeXlive 2013 and 2015...

When I look into the log file of a compiled document a lot of old paths can be found. One example: `(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)`

However, the path `/usr/local/texlive/2013` is not existing anymore. The new install path is `/usr/share/texmf-dist` as far as I know. How can LuaLaTeX still use the old path and don't warn about missing files (for those that were existent before)? And how can I change this behaviour to forget about old paths?

I have tried a texhash without success. And I looked into the PATH variable (which needed to be changed by the old manual install) and it doesn't hold the old paths anymore...
Also a `kpsewhich tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex` gives the correct
`/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be clear: Your old installation is gone. Now, we have to look, whether you have included the old path into your PATH variable and forgot all about it.

There are some "hidden" files on the top level of your HOME folder (/home/monceros84/ ). Their names start with a dot, e.g. ".profile" or ".bash". Please have a look into those files: Do they contain something like

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
```

-- then please delete that. There may be more lines pointing to doc and info of the old texlive installation as well. Or even better: comment them out by adding a "#" to the beginning of each such line. Save the file.

Then log out and log in again.